# Visual Basic Setting Labels in an Array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm writing a little program in Visual Basic in Studio '10. I have a series of eight arrays that I need to set text too in a for loop. I need to set the text based off of the label number(eg label 1 gets word1, label 2 gets word2) Is there a way to create a array, then set my existing labels inside this array so I can then say something such as

```
for i = 1 to 8
    subsets(i).Text = words(w + i)
next
```

- 'i' being the variable of a for loop
- subsets being the array name.
- 'words' is a array containing strings
  I'm a bit new at this, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array (or list) of `Label` and add each label control to it.

This will allow you to loop and assign values as you describe.

```
Dim subsets As New List(Of Label)
subsets.Add(label1)
subsets.Add(label2)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to base the word on the label's name, you should make an array or a list as Oded suggested. You can then use the [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx) method to remove the word Label from your labels name, cast it to an int and subtract 1 since arrays in .Net are 0 based.

Something like this.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim subsets(7) As Label
    Dim words() As String = New String() {"this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "text", "replacement", "."}
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        subsets(0) = Label1
        subsets(1) = Label2
        subsets(2) = Label3
        subsets(3) = Label4
        subsets(4) = Label5
        subsets(5) = Label6
        subsets(6) = Label7
        subsets(7) = Label8

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each lbl As Label In subsets
            lbl.Text = words(CInt(lbl.Name.Remove(0, 5)) - 1)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying to do, though I may be wrong

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim words() As String = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"}
    Dim subsets() As Control = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6, Label7, Label8}

    For i = 0 To 7
        subsets(i).Text = words(i)
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

This assigns the words array to the labels text property